# Is it possible to use Hyper-V VM without booting into host OS

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm a newbie in Hyper-V / Virtualization. I'm trying to explore the Hyper-V feature that came bundled with Windows 8.1. On reading some online tutorials, here what I discovered about Hyper-V.

- Hyper-V is a type-1 hypervisor that is available in Windows 8 / 8.1.
- Though it is type-1, it is used as type-2 since we bring-up the Hyper-V mgmt console to control / spawn the VMs.

Now my doubt is, Since Hyper-V is claimed to be a type-1 hypervisor, wouldn't it be possible to directly boot into one of the Hyper-V VMs, without the need for the host OS (i.e Windows 8.1) to boot completely.

The reason for my query is, if host OS is there, i.e only the necessary hypervisor services are there, then I can provide some little more extra resources to the guest OS.

Advance thanks in answering this newbie's query.

Answer (score 1):

Tier-1 means the HyperVisior gots direct access to the Hardware. Tier-2 has just access to the OS, and the OS to the Hardware.

There is a special Windows Server 2012 HyperV Version available, which comes without GUI, that needs less Resources by itself to run. BTW: It's free!

With Windows 2016 there will come "Windows Nano Servers", it's a minimal OS with just Infrastructur Features like Hyper-V and Dockerization Service. It just could be managed with Powershell.

Optional there is XenServer (6.5sp1) Tier1 Hypervisor which is OpenSource and free.

Comment: So, you mean to say, "in Windows 8.1" this cannot be achieved ?

Comment: @VISWAKSP - It isn't possible out of the box and without third-party software.

Comment: @Ramhound . Thanks. I think that answered my question